# Istancing Collections with an istanced object inside doesn't work

Tags: modeling, collections

the title might be confusing so:

Blender Version 3.5.0

I'm trying to Istance this "Gala table" on plane Vertices:
[image]
but this collection has two more object (Mise en Place, Chiar) that are istanced on a 10 Vertices shape with the following method:

- Select object to be istanced > Select istancing shape > CTRL P > Vertex
- Select Istancing shape (like "Chair Loop") and do the following:

[image]

but they doesn't appear when istancing "Gala Table" on another shape Vertices when using this Geometry Node(or the past method):
[image]

If you know another method please let me know.
Thank you

Comment: Vertex parent instancing is a legacy method of instancing. It is not well supported with modern workflows, and will be phased out in future versions of Blender. It would be advised to use a more robust method of instancing like using geometry nodes that is more future peoof